# why there is several crond process on centos OS

Tags: centos, cron

I have a server which CPU usage is very high, and I find there is many crond process on this server. I can not understand why this occur.Anyone know the reason? Please tell me.
When I run "ps aux | grep crond" on this server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNfeQ.png)

Comment: Please paste textual console output instead of a screen capture image.

Answer (score 0):

crond forks a process for each job it executes. In your case, it looks like several jobs are being started every five minutes. All of them, though, appear to be waiting for I/O (that's the meaning of the "D" process state in the 8th column of ps output, according to [the ps man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html)), and thus are not contributing to CPU load.

If you want to know what's eating the CPU, start with [top](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html).

Comment: when the server has several crond process, I can not connect it. Now I had restarted it. And the problem has been solved,but I can't find the real reason.

Comment: The wedged cronds might be a symptom of another problem, such as a failing disk or bad NFS mount — I've seen both cause "D" process states in the past.

Answer (score 0):

crond is not the cause of the problem, suggest you use top to check Cost the process of high performance.

Comment: When it occured, I could't login the server.

Comment: try to monitor the situation under the situation of high load, the monitoring frequency can be set a little lower